# Create numeric value from character value in sas

Tags: sas, numeric

I want to conver a code like "13232C" to a numeric value. Maybe assign values 1 to 26 for A to Z. Then the new code would be "132323".

Comment: Is there always just 1 character value?

Answer (score 4):

This code will work if there is just 1 letter in the code.  If there are more then you will need to scan through each one to get the value.  I've calculated the letter value (1-26) by subtracting 64 from the ASCII value (A=65), making sure to convert the letter to upper case if necessary.  I've also assumed that the letter always appears at the end of the string

```
data have;
input code $;
datalines;
132323C
24578D
5147896G
;
run;

data want;
set have;
new_code=input(cats(compress(code,,'dk'),rank(compress(upcase(code),,'ak'))-64),best12.);
run;
```

Comment: I should probably add that you may want to keep the new variable as character if you need to reference the number calculated from the letter.  This will only be possible if your original string is a fixed length, in my example I've used variable lengths.  Hopefully I've given you sufficient method to enable modification for your purposes.

Comment: Nice solution. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Keith's solution is probably better for most uses, but I can't help seeing this as a good chance to play with PROC FCMP (Function Compile).  This works nicely in the case where you have A-I only; starting with J it won't work since I'm only allowing a single character's space.  If it can have 2 digits, the FCMP would need to be changed to do what Keith's solution does.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.trial;
function cton(charvar $) $;
  do n = 1 to length(charvar);
   if 48 le rank(char(charvar,n)) le 57 then ;
   else substr(charvar,n,1) = put(rank(upcase(char(charvar,n)))-64,1.);
   put charvar;
  end;
return (charvar);
endsub;

quit;
options cmplib=work.funcs;

data test;
x="23456CAB";
y = cton(x);
put x= y=;
run;
```

I also return it as a character, but that's not important - you could return it as a numeric if you prefer (I saw the " " in the original question).